# Enumerator returning each line of a file, but chomped

Tags: ruby

I would like to write a method returning an enumerator (similar to the one which is returned by `File::foreach`), which returns every line of a file in succession, but chomped. My first approach was

```
def chomped_lines(filename)
  File.foreach(filename).map(&:chomp).each
end
```

and to use it as

```
my_enum = chomped_lines('my_file.txt')
....
my_enum.each { |line| .... }
```

I guess, Enumerator::lazy could be used here somehow, but in any case, the code should run on Ruby 1.9.3, which means I don't have lazy enumerators yet.

What would be a good way to write such an enumerator?

This seems to work, but if I understand this right (please correct me if I'm wrong), the file will be slurped into memory as a whole into memory, in order to apply `map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the enumerator as follows. First, let's create a file for demonstration.

```
str =<<_
Now is the
time for all
Rubiests to
come to the
aid of their
bowling team.
_

fname = "temp"
File.write(fname, str)
  #=> 75
```

[IO#foreach](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) without a block returns an enumerator:

```
efe = File.foreach(fname)
  #=> #<Enumerator: File:foreach("temp")>
```

so we need to merely embed this enumerator in another that chomps the newline character from a line:

```
echomp = Enumerator.new do |y|
  loop do
    y << efe.next.chomp
  end
end
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007fbe128837b8>:each>
```

Let's try it:

```
echomp.next
  #=> "Now is the" 
echomp.next
  #=> "time for all" 
echomp.next
  #=> "Rubiests to" 
echomp.next
  #=> "come to the" 
echomp.next
  #=> "aid of their" 
echomp.next
  #=> "bowling team." 
echomp.next
  #=> StopIteration: iteration reached an end
```

You could of course wrap this in a method:

```
def foreach_with_chomp(fname)
  efe = File.foreach(fname)
  Enumerator.new do |y|
    loop do
      y << efe.next.chomp
    end
  end
end

foreach_with_chomp(fname).each { |s| print "#{s} " }
Now is the time for all Rubiests to come to the aid of their bowling team.
```

Comment: If I understand your approach correctly, by putting the `foreach` enumerator (`efe.next`) inside the loop of the new Enumerator, you avoid slurping the whole file into memory. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

I've written a class that I believe does what you want it to.  It's also posted as a gist at https://gist.github.com/keithrbennett/9f126fa17d9df5e3aacaf638b198dfb9.

There is some code after the class definition that exercises the class in a couple of ways.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class ChompedFileLines
  include Enumerable

  def initialize(filespec)
    @filespec = filespec
  end

  def each
      File.foreach(@filespec) { |line| yield line.chomp }
  end
end

# Exercise the class:

FILESPEC = '/usr/share/dict/words'

chomped_file_lines = ChompedFileLines.new(FILESPEC)
puts; p chomped_file_lines; puts
chomped_file_lines.first(10).each { |line| p line }

chomped_file_lines_enum = ChompedFileLines.new(FILESPEC).to_enum
puts; p chomped_file_lines_enum; puts
10.times { p chomped_file_lines_enum.next }
```

Comment: Indeed, this seems to work well, though I personally don't like much the fact that I have to create a new class just for this. The solution proposed by @CarySwoveland avoids this issue. In the end, it seems to be a matter of taste.

Comment: Although it may seem like a big deal to create a new class, that class is extremely short and simple.  It may be a matter of taste, but for me, the class organizes the code in a way that's easier to follow.  In addition, this approach provides higher cohesiveness / lower coupling in that the enumeration mechanism and the behavior executed during the enumerations is separated (though to be fair, this could also be accomplished in Cary's code by parameterizing the behavior in the form of a code block.)